# error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token with indexed or iterated string

Tags: c++, string, g++

This is the strangest error to me.

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 *.cpp -o lab2
lab2.cpp: In function ‘void toAlpha(std::string&)’:
lab2.cpp:18:19: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  for(int i = 0, i < str.length(), ++i){
               ^
lab2.cpp:18:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
lab2.cpp:18:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
lab2.cpp:18:38: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  for(int i = 0, i < str.length(), ++i){
                                  ^
```

From what I have read. This error usually comes from something above the line mentioned. However, it is almost the first function in the code. Maybe you can help see what my eyes can't.

FYI the purpose of the function is to convert all non-alpha characters to spaces.

This happens no matter whether I access through an index or iterators.

Here is the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include "print.h"

using namespace std;

typedef map<string,list<int>> WORDMAP;

/* makes symbols turn into spaces */

void toAlpha(string& str){
  for(int i = 0, i < str.length(), ++i){
    if(!isalpha(str[i])){
       str[i] = ' ';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've used commas in your if's where you should be using semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `;` in your for loop statement.

Comment: Sometimes we only need another pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to incorrect `for` loop syntax

change:

```
for(int i = 0, i < str.length(), ++i)
```

to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
//           ^                 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use semicolons instead of commas:

```
void toAlpha(string& str){
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i){
    if(!isalpha(str[i])){
       str[i] = ' ';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop syntax goes like this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i){
```

notice the semicolons instead of commas.